# Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool failed

Tags: java, web-services, maven

I am getting following exception while hitting wsconsume in maven build:

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for MyProject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 40, column 14

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsimport (MyAPI) on project MyProject:Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool failed
```

RELATED POM:

```
                        <execution>
                            <id>MyAPI</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
                                <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>myprod.jaxb</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                                <xadditionalHeaders>true</xadditionalHeaders>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <args>
                                    <arg>-Xnocompile</arg>
                                </args>
                                <wsdlUrls>
                                    <wsdlUrl>http://my.us:61168/MyProxy.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                </wsdlUrls>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```

It was working earlier but suddenly it stopped working. No changes are done from my end.

Java 1.7

Netbeans 8.1

Comment: Have you resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of java version that runs eclipse. In some cases it makes an exception. Just add or change -vm argument in eclipse.ini. For me it works for 1.8.0_66.

Just put in eclipse.ini file line:

```
-vm C:\Java\JDK\bin\javaw.exe
```

If you have java in "*program files*" directory, remeber to write it in non space convention like Progra~1 and above -vmarg

Answer (score 0):

check the java version in the environment variables , whether you set the same version or not , I had the same issue , I set 1.8 in my system variables and I am trying to build with 1.7

Answer (score 0):

it is not related to java version, we need to upgrade the versions of jaxws-maven-plugin,jaxb-impl to 2.2.`0 or more. if you still face the same issue please build your project with fresh repository(sometimes,it may faile to take the existed repository).in my case it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using IntelliJ IDE. I changed Java version to Open JDK 14. This JDK version was also set in the JAVA_HOME for the system.
After reading about this problem it seems Java version was the problem. So i changed SDK within IntelliJ IDE, but that didn;t work.
The problem resolved only after changing JAVA_HOME and pointed to JDK 8 version.